# Could not load file or assembly - .Net Core Http Trigger

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio Code to write an Azure Function (HTTP Trigger). I added
`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` as a dependency. Visual Studio code resolves and pulls down the package. Here's my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <DefineConstants>NETCOREAPP3_1</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.15.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I run and invoke my method in the .cs file that imports System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt I get the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.15.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can verify that visual studio code has copied the dlls into the build/debug folder.

As far as I can tell the package is compatible with netcoreapp3.1:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/6.15.1

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Yep didn't fix it unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with that version of that package. Going back a few versions resolved the issue.

Comment: What leads you to think there's an issue with that version? Going back to v6.10.0 solves this for us when using the package `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect`.